# Nginx Ingress Controller installation using helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress, helm3

I'm trying to install `Nginx Ingress Controller` using below helm command but getting below errors..

```
$ helm upgrade --install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx \
>   --repo https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx \
>   --namespace ingress-nginx --create-namespace
Release "ingress-nginx" does not exist. Installing it now.
Error: chart requires kubeVersion: >=1.20.0-0 which is incompatible with Kubernetes v1.19.16
```

Since i use `Kubernetes v1.19.16`, So kindly let me know the suitable stable version for my Kubernetes cluster version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the message:

```
Error: chart requires kubeVersion: >=1.20.0-0 which is incompatible with Kubernetes v1.19.16
```

The version of the chart you are trying to install requires you to have 1.20.0 or higher. So you can either:

1. Upgrade your cluster to 1.20 or later

or:

2. Install an older version of the chart using the `--version` switch with helm